Azure SQL Database Back-up with Powershell: cannot open server "domainname.com" requested by the login. The login failed..'
I have a script to export a bacpac file to the storage account. The script is running for a while, cannot open server "domainname.com" requested by the login. The login failed..'.
As the username I am using username@domainname.com (my admin account) and in the error it is pointing to the domain name of my username.
$GetStorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName
$GetStorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName).Value[0]
$GetStorageAccount.Context

$SQLBackup = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ServerName $ServerName `
-StorageKeyType StorageAccessKey -StorageKey $GetStorageAccountKey `
-StorageUri "$($STorageUri)/$($ContainerName)/$($DBBackupName)"  `
-AdministratorLogin $UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force)

do{

    $GetSQLBackupStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseActivity -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ServerName $ServerName | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "InProgress"}

    if($GetSQLBackupStatus.state -eq "InProgress"){
        $Progress = 1
    }else{

        $Progress = 0
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Back-up process is still active.."
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Backup-process has" $GetSQLBackupStatus.PercentComplete "% completed."

}while($Progress -eq 1)


In my case the solution was to use SQL authentication instead of a Microsoft Entra ID.
